# How to give photo library images selection status in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I use this code to show photo picker to select photos in Jetpack Compose

```
val images = remember {
   mutableStateOf(emptyList<Uri>())
}
val imagesLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.PickMultipleVisualMedia(4)
) {
    isEnabled.value = true
    images.value = it
}


// Button to show photo picker

Button(onClick = {           imagesLauncher.launch(PickVisualMediaRequest(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly))
}) {
    Text(text = "Tap")
}
```

But I can't give photo library which images are selected so that if photo library appears again, `images` variable will be empty list.

If it is possible, I wanna use Binding in SwiftUI to retrieve the status.

How do i fix it, please help

Comment: You need to make custom photo picker so that you can show that image is already selected.